# Flask sqlalchemy - many to many relationship - filtering on children level

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

my filter on children doesn't work. I am not sure, what it is done in wrong way.

country.py

```
product_country = Table('product_country', Base.metadata,
  Column('product_id', Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True),
  Column('country_id', Integer, ForeignKey('country.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Country(Base):
  __tablename__="country"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(200))
  products = relationship(Product, secondary=product_country, backref='countries')
```

product.py

```
class Product(Base):
  __tablename__="product"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  color = Column(Integer)
  ....
```

then sqlalchemy search:

```
country = s.query(Country).join(Country.products).filter(Country.id==1).filter(Product.color==1).first()
```

Well, I get country with id=1, what is what I want, but in list country.products, I would expect only products with color = 1, but there are all products assigned to country. Please could you help me. Thank you

Comment: Can you post a more complete snippet of `Product`, as it is we can't see how `Product.color` is defined.

Comment: @bgse - I have updated Product class where color is defined now. But it is not about definition of color. You can replace color by id in sqlalchemy query and there is the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a misunderstanding. The relationship loading is separate from your query, for good reasons. In other words the join you've used is not used to eagerly load the relationship. You could instruct the query that it contains an eager load join with `contains_eager()`, and read ["the zen of joined eager loading"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-joined-eager-loading) in order to understand and ["Using contains_eager() to load a custom-filtered collection result"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result) for an example how to do what you're trying. In your case just add

```
options(contains_eager(Country.products))
```

to your query.